# Creating new columns in DataFrames under some condition

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I'm trying to create a new column in my dataframe, but its values must follow some rule. For example, if the value of the variable `Venda` is less than 200, then the variable `Comissão` must be 0.

```
if (df['Venda']<200):
    df['Comissão']=0
    df['Direito a Bonus']='Não'
elif (df['Venda']>=200) & (df['Venda']<250):
    df['Comissão']=0.5*df['Venda']
    df['Direito a Bonus']='Sim'
else:
    df['Comissão']=0.7*df['Venda']
    df['Direito a Bonus']='Sim'
```

Running this code, I get the error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Numpy.select()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and [Numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
c1 = df['Venda']<200
c2 = df['Venda']<250

df['Comissão'] = np.select([c1, c2], [0, 0.5], default=0.7)*df['Venda']
df['Direito a Bonus'] = np.where(c1, 'Não', 'Sim')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and then use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine them:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Venda':[100,150,200,205,210,250,251]})
print(df)
def check(val):
    if (val<200):
        return [0,'Não']
    elif ((val>=200) and (val<250)):
        return [0.5*val,'Sim']
    else:
        return [0.7*val,'Sim']

df2=pd.DataFrame(list(df.Venda.apply(check)), columns=['Comissão','Direito a Bonus'])
df=pd.concat([df,df2], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Venda
0    100
1    150
2    200
3    205
4    210
5    250
6    251

   Venda  Comissão Direito a Bonus
0    100       0.0             Não
1    150       0.0             Não
2    200     100.0             Sim
3    205     102.5             Sim
4    210     105.0             Sim
5    250     175.0             Sim
6    251     175.7             Sim
```